# Adding MIME type in SP Online

Tags: mime-type, sp-online

Is there any way to add MIME types in SP online? We have added in on-premise before at the web application level and need to do the same in SP online.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not possible. Some files doesn't have mapped MIME types, which means they can't be saved to SharePoint Online.

Reference: [Adding MIME types in SharePoint Online](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/adding-mime-types-in-sharepoint-online/00028722-2d47-4355-8c6a-5ce6a0e592a1)

The answer suggests voting on a request at [User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/282887-sharepoint-hybrid-or-migration-to-office365/suggestions/15287109-add-custom-mime-type).